# New connection from ::1 on port 8883. Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting

Tags: cmd, mqtt, mosquitto, broker

I'm trying to connect/publish from broker to web, but it's not work.

I am already searching on the internet, but cannot find anything to solve it.

example when someone told me to untag bridge_protocol on mosquitto.conf , it's not work but get another error.

my mosquitto version is 1.4.9
I think something need to change on mosquitto.conf

When I try mosquitto -v -c mosquitto.conf
the result is :

```
mosquitto version 1.4.9
config loaded from mosquitto.conf
opening ipv4 and 6 socket on port 8883
new connection from :11 on port 8883.
socket error on client <unknown>, disconecting.
```

I can connect/publish from Broker to web.

[image]

Comment: It will help if you add your mosquitto configuration to the post

Comment: Please do not post images of log output, post the actual text, formatted properly as this is easier to search for. Also please edit the question to include your mosquitto.conf and details of the client you are using.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve here ? Which program is connecting with mqtt broker and also mention if it is using cert based authentication for connecting

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to make a guess here...

It looks from the log that you have just changed the default port mosquitto is listening on from 1883 to 8883 most likely with the `port` configuration option.

You are then trying to connect to this from a webpage using the Paho JavaScript client.

This is failing because while you have changed the port you have not told mosquitto that it needs to use the `websocket` protocol for that port. This is because the Paho JavaScript client can only use MQTT over WebSockets not native MQTT.

The way to fix this is to reset the default port back to 1883 and then add a listener on port 8883 specifically set up to use WebSockets.

e.g. a mosquitto.conf like this:

```
port 1883

listener 8883
protocol websockets
```

Comment: sorry, thank u for all The answer help me so much . So I just add more listener on my mqtt and it's work guys. thank u